# Hosting node.js

Tags: node.js, hosting, paas

Is there any PAAS provider where a small, productive, non-profit node.js application can be hosted for up to 10Euro/month.

- no.de: for development only, no predictions about availability
- heroku: when quotas are not enough, it gets bloody expensive

Comment: have you looked at MediaTemple? I don't know if they support nodejs for non-root, but if you get root you can pretty much do what you want. There's also linode, rackspace, and slicehost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a free-tier Amazon EC2 micro-instance ?

Answer (score 2):

Try [IBM BlueMix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/). They give you 375 GB-hours a month, which is 1 Instance with 512 MB RAM running non-stop for free.

Alternatively, try [OpenShift](http://openshift.com) with 3 gears for free.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at nodestr.com ?  It came up in a search as well as your question in a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Heroku and it tends to be pricey in the middle-run. On the contrary Nodejitsu is more appealing in terms of price.

https://www.nodejitsu.com/pricing/

Do not expect miracle tough :)

Answer (score 0):

IBM Bluemix is better one in terms of pricing/reliability/security.You can follow below link for having details on pricing and specifications:

http://blog.balfes.net/2014/02/27/what-the-heck-is-bluemix-and-why-do-i-care-about-it/